# Approximation of $\sqrt{2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, approximation

Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence define by
\begin{cases}
x_1 = 1 \\
x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left( x_n + \frac{2}{x_n} \right)
\end{cases}.
Show that $1\leqslant x_n \leqslant\frac{3}{2}\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I've tried by induction. My induction hypothesis was the vadility of $1\leqslant x_k \leqslant\frac{3}{2}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. From that it is easy to show that $x_{k+1}\geqslant 1$. In fact, $1\leqslant x_k$ implies $3\leqslant x_k^2+2$ and $x_k\leqslant\frac{3}{2}$ implies $1\leqslant\frac{3}{2x_k}$. Then,
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= \frac{x_k^2+2}{2x_k}\\
 &\geqslant \frac{3}{2x_k}\\
&\geqslant 1.
\end{align}
But I'm stuck with $x_{k+1}\leqslant\frac{3}{2}$. I only get $x_{k+1}\leqslant\frac{17}{8}$, way over $\frac{3}{2}$.
I think there must be some preliminay result that makes this last part easier, but I do not know. Any hint would be enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show how you are getting $\frac{17}8$?

Comment: You could show using calculus methods that the function $\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{2}{x})$ has a max of $1.5$ at $x=1$ on the interval $[1,1.5]$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2 , https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/newton-sqrt.pdf

Comment: I was trying to make the same approach I did with $1\leqslant x_{k+1}$. By the inductive hypothesis we have \begin{align} x_{k+1} &= \frac{ x_k^2+2 }{ 2x_k } \\ &\leqslant \frac{ 9/4+2 }{2x_k} \\ &\leqslant \frac{ 9/4 }{2\cdot 1} \\  &=\frac{17}{8} \end{align}. But I already know how to prove this last part. I've written a solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discussed this question with a friend and he gave me a excellent idea as I insisted in proving it by induction. Follow the last part for $x_{k+1}\leqslant\frac{3}{2}$:

First notice that

\begin{align}
x_{k+1} - \frac{3}{2} &= \frac{x_k}{2} + \frac{1}{x_k} - \frac{3}{2} \\
 &=  \frac{ x_k^2 - 3x_k + 2 }{ 2x_k } \\
 &= \frac{(x_k-1)(x_k-2)}{ 2x_k }
\end{align}

Now, looking at that last quotient, with the inductive hypothesis in mind, we have $x_k-1\geqslant 0$ and $x_k\leqslant\frac{3}{2}<2\ \therefore\ x_k-2 < 0$. Which let us conclude
\begin{equation}
x_{k+1} - \frac{3}{2} = \frac{ (x_k-1)(x_k-2) }{ 2x_k } \leqslant 0 \quad \implies \quad x_{k+1}\leqslant\frac{3}{2}.
\end{equation}

I appreciated all solutions in here.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $x_n$ is decreasing after the second term, which is $3/2$.

Proof:

First,

$$x_{n+1}-\sqrt2=\frac{1}{2x_n}(x_n-\sqrt2)^2\ge0$$

Therefore $x_n\ge\sqrt{2}$ for all $n>1$.

And

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{x_n}-x_n)$$

But for $n>1$, $x_n\ge\sqrt2$ hence $\dfrac{2}{x_n}\le\sqrt2$ and $x_{n+1}-x_n\le0$.

Therefore, $\sqrt2\le x_n\le\frac32$ for all $n>1$, and $1\le x_n\le\frac32$ for all $n\ge1$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $x_n \leq \frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: @Math23 The answer is the first sentence: The sequence $x_n$ is decreasing after the second term, which is $3/2$. And of course $x_1\le3/2$ as well. Then I *prove* the sequence is indeed decreasing. Decreasing means $3/2= x_2\ge x_3\ge x_4\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just Newton's method. However, since the $x_n$  values are rational, we  have an alternative for discussing the accuracy..

We begin with $x = \frac{3}{2},$   that is rational $x = \frac{p}{q}$   with $p^2 - 2 q^2 = 1.$  The next step turns out the same: if $x_n = \frac{p}{q}$   with $p^2 - 2 q^2 = 1,$   then calculation gives
$$x_{n+1}  =  \frac{p^2 + 2 q^2}{2pq}$$  Then we ask about
$$ (p^2 + 2 q^2)^2  - 2 (2pq)^2 = p^4 + 4 p^2 q^2 + 4 q^4 - 8p^2 q^2 = (p^2 - 2 q^2)^2  = 1   $$

Next, how good is the approximation to $\sqrt 2?$  When $p^2 - 2 q^2 = 1,$ we have $ \left( \frac{p}{q} \right)^2 - 2 = \frac{1}{q^2} ,$   so a quick outcome is $\frac{p}{q} > \sqrt 2  $   and $\frac{p}{q} + \sqrt 2  >  \sqrt 8,$   after which $\frac{1}{\frac{p}{q} + \sqrt 2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt 8}.$  But  $$(\frac{p}{q} + \sqrt 2) (\frac{p}{q} - \sqrt 2)  =  \frac{1}{q^2},  $$
$$\frac{1}{\frac{p}{q} + \sqrt 2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt 8},$$
$$ (\frac{p}{q} - \sqrt 2)  <  \frac{1}{q^2 \, \sqrt 8 \;} \; .  $$

Comment: Your last paragraph derives from *Diophantine Approximation*, correct? @WillJagy  =)